# Long form on tablet, show all questions open or use expand/collapse sections

Tags: forms, navigation, tablet

Im designing a long form on tablet. The form is made up of 5 case studies and 8 questions per case study so 40 questions.

The form is linear but users can choose to jump between sections (i.e. you dont have to fill in each question to get to the next)

My plan is to use LHN for case studies but to display each of the 8 questions on the page. My question is should i display questions all open (they can just scroll to see it) or do i show a collapse view as per image so users get an understanding of the form.

The form is an interview form and users (interviews) will be reusing the same form for each interview[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the answer with you. I would suggest you use collapsible tab view according to the section. As you mentioned that you have 5 case studies with 8 questions each case studies contain so make those 5 case studies as an accordion view and then each question in it to an accordion as well. I am attaching an image for better understanding. Hope I clearly understand your question and this will help you.

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above-mentioned answer, you can mention on the screen that user has to fill only 8 questions per tab to let the user know how much work is required from his side. 
.